# How to design schema in GraphQL considering input types for mutation?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Does this schema look correct?

```
type User {
    id : ID!
    username : String!
    email : String!
    name : String!
}

input UserInput {
    username : String!
    email : String!
    name : String!
}

mutation createNewUser($usr: UserInput!) {
  createUser(user: $usr)
}
```

As internal id for the user will be assigned upon user creation, Should there be separate `type` and `input` in this schema or **User** could be made `input`? So that schema looks like this

```
input User {
    id: ID
    username : String!
    email : String!
    name : String!
}

mutation createNewUser($usr: User!) {
  createUser(user: $usr) : User
}
```

Comment: I believe your initial approach is correct based on the docs: http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right on the money in your first approach. The `id` field can not be null (`id: ID!`) and it can not have a value when you need to create the user, so you need to have another input type for it.

As [mattdionis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3084511/mattdionis) also pointed out, there's a very similiar sample in the [docs](http://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/).

Answer (score 0):

Your schema should be

```
const typeDefinitions = `
type User {
    id : ID!
    username : String!
    email : String!
    name : String!
}

input UserInput {
    username : String!
    email : String!
    name : String!
}

type Mutation {
  createUser(user: UserInput) User
}

schema {
  mutation:Mutation
}
`;

export default [typeDefinitions];
```